# iOS - NSMutableArray shows objects out of bounds on setting property

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have implemented the following code to assign NSMutableArray to a property -

```
NSMutableArray * anArray = [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"tags"];
    NSLog(@"The array length is=%d",[anArray count]);
    for (NSString *s in anArray) {

        NSLog(@"you are %@", s);

    }
    [self setActiveTagArray:anArray];
```

It prints out the string values fine. But in the setter function, if I place a breakpoint I see that it shows there are two objects but they are "Out of Scope". What does this mean? What am I doing wrong? My getter also does not fetch any values. The property functions -

```
-(void)setActiveTagArray:(NSMutableArray *)tags
{
   activeTagArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   activeTagArray = tags;
   //NSLog(@"%@",[activeTagArray count]);
}

-(NSMutableArray *)getActiveTagArray
{
   return activeTagArray;
}
```

Comment: where do you place that breakpoint ? in the setter, you don't need to allocate and init a new array, just assign **and retain** the new reference. Also, you need to **release** the previous one.

Comment: @user971401, If this code is under ARC you shouldn't use `release`. "Out of scope" is a debugger message, i guess that all right with you arrays. Try to `NSLog` your second array in setter.

Comment: @beryllium - i didn't write that thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is activeTagArray a class variable as well as a property. Consider using _activeTagArray as the class variable name. And then in the .m file just use `@synthesize activeTagArray = _activeTagArray;`, and for get the second two methods completely.

Response to comment:

You said "I have implemented the following code to assign NSMutableArray to a property". I took this to mean you have "`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *activeTagArray;`" in your .h file. If this is the case then you would access it thru `otherObject'sNameForYourClassHere.activeTagArray`.

@synthesize create accessors & mutators for you.

Comment: how would I them access the variable from another class?

Comment: @Suchi. Updated answer in response to comment.